# Rhino conversion java.lang.String to JavaScript String

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

`Context.javaToJS` seems to just pass java.lang.Strings straight through.

I am sandboxing the JavaScript (according to http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/01/02/sandboxing-rhino-in-java/) so `java.lang.String` is not useable in JavaScript unless I punch holes through the `ClassShutter` (which I would rather not do).

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
ScriptContext context = engine.getContext();
context.setAttribute("jsString", "I am Java String", ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
context.setAttribute("jsBoolean", true, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
context.setAttribute("jsNumber",  123456, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
engine.eval("function getValueAndType(obj){return obj + ' - ' + typeof obj;}");
Assert.assertEquals("Something wen wrong", "I am Java String - string", engine.eval("getValueAndType(jsString)"));
Assert.assertEquals("Something wen wrong", "true - boolean", engine.eval("getValueAndType(jsBoolean)"));
Assert.assertEquals("Something wen wrong", "123456 - number", engine.eval("getValueAndType(jsNumber)"));
```

Comment: Yes, the setAttributes seems to create js strings, while Context.javaToJS just passes through Java strings.  I suppose that I could fudge things that way.  But ideally would like returned values.  Thanks.